# Error in gradle build after adding facebook sdk dependency to android studio

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate Facebook login using firebase in my app, but when I add the dependency

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

I get errors in gradle build

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File -> Project Structure -> app -> dependencies

-> delete(-) 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

-> add(+) library dependencies-> search:facebook

-> choose 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.X.X' -> ok!

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling all your `com.android.support` libraries to the lastest version and the same with your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

It worked for me